# A program that update records from local server to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a local data base for different different client on multiple terminals, and i have replica of database to the remote server, i want in a windows application on button click the data from the local should get updated to the remote server for some client id.
How can i achieve this? Could somebody suggest me on this.
Or link of reference.

Comment: What research have you done so far? This sounds pretty trivial and could be completed with basic ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to synchronize databases. There's different approches to do that:

1. Manually detect differences between two databases and insert/update the differences. Now, your database should be in a certain format for that to work, for example one could use GUID instead of incremental integers for ID's in a relational database. And you also need a created/updated dates for each row.
2. You could also check ouf the Sync Framework, there's more documentation on how do to deal with synchronization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608